# iphone/ipad development, send info to server

Tags: iphone

Planning to configure database on server site, and need to send info submitted by user from iphone/ipad to the server. What is the best way of doing it in the xcode?

Answer (score 1):

ASIHTTPRequest might be a good & easy solution. It lets you upload and download files to and from a server... It implements super-easy, a few lines of code... just see the "setup/install" and "how to use" pages [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the pages (php for example) on your server how the information should be sent, but I use `NSURLConnection` to send information and `$_POST['variable']` to read the information server side.

I'll see if I can find an example of how I've used it.

This is my objective-c code to send information to a server:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localFile];

        // setting up the URL to post to
        NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@upload.php", ROOT_URL];


        // setting up the request object now
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];



        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [urlString release];

        /*
         add some header info now
         we always need a boundary when we post a file
         also we need to set the content type

         You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
         as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
         */
        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        /*
         now lets create the body of the post
         */
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    


        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyyHHmmss"];

        NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];
        [format release];
        [now release];



        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"recording%@%@.mov", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], dateString];

        filename = [filename stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: video/quicktime\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // now lets make the connection to the web
        [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks James for detailed info. The server site will be Google App Engine, java based. My question is mostly about the iphone programming portion, the best implementation way, considering possible slow wifi connection to pass it to server site.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used JSP, so not certain how to pass the information specifically to Java, but I assume it has something to get POST information?

If you find my answer useful, please don't forget to upvote and accept it at correct. ;)